# I want to helights my div using loop in angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

Better understanding for I mentioned the Images.

If i am not selecting anything of div Property, the default style(css) should be [Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSwHG.jpg) , alteast selected one div. but here, [problem is unable to selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8l6Gj.jpg).

this is my component :

```
<div *ngFor="let item of data; let i = index;" (click)="setRow(i)" 
    [ngClass]="{'highlight': selectedIndex===i}" class="cycleHover"
>
    {{item}}
</div>
```

css :

```
.cycleHover{
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    margin: 4px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 14px;
    // line-height: 18px;

    color: #010103;
}

.highlight{ 
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    margin: 4px;
    color: #737D88;
    box-shadow: 0px 4px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    border-radius: 24px;
}
```

ts:

```
selectedIndex: any;

data: any[] = ["D", "W", "M", "Q", "Y"];

 setRow(_index: number) {
    this.selectedIndex = _index;
  }
```

Comment: Just initialize `selectedIndex` with a proper index, then your highlighting works.

Comment: You should probably also set the specific type of vaiables not to `any`, but to the specific types (`number` or `string` in this case).

Answer (score 0):

As a side note, you can make clearer, more concise code like this :

```html
<div *ngFor="let item of data" 
    (click)="selected = data" 
    [class.highlight]="selected === data"
    class="cycleHover"
>
    {{item}}
</div>
```

```js
data = ["D", "W", "M", "Q", "Y"];
selected = this.data[0]; // Or undefined depending on what you want
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to select first as a default then change declaration of selectedIndex in your ts file like this:

```
selectedIndex:number=0;
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to select middle as a default then put this code in ngOnInit(){}

```
this.setRow(Math.floor(this.data.length/2));
```